# phpunit memory_limit parameter does not apply

Tags: php, macos, phpunit, xdebug, memory-limit

I've just installed phpunit via pear in a mac osx 10.7 and everything works fine except I got memory limit errors (xdebug enabled for reports).

I tried to add the `-d memory_limit=512M` parameter to phpunit but it is not applying because, on the very first error, I added `var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit')); exit;` and it prints string(3) "32M"

So, why is it not being applied?

Besides that, if I run

```
php -d memory_limit=256M -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit');"
```

it echoes "256M"

Is it possible that phpunit is not executing same php?

Comment: Did you try `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M')`?

Comment: @afuzzyllama It works but i don't get why it doesn't with command line

Comment: This is going to sound stupid, but what happens if you try `phpunit -dmemory_limit=512M`?

Comment: Does PHPUnit even accept `-d`?

Comment: In another machine it worked for me

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes you can set every php option with `phpunit -d` that can be set with `ini_set`.

[You already opened a bug over in the phpunit bug tracker](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/456) but well I'm going for the more verbose answer here

Reproduce to show it works in general:

```
echo "<?php var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit')); " > foo.php

phpunit -d memory_limit=12M --bootstrap foo.php
```

Produces:

```
string(3) "12M"
PHPUnit 3.6.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

---

But phpunit only applies this option once before the first test is run!

So chances are your code is somewhere changing the memory limit back to `32M` which is something phpunit can't "fix".

Same goes for setting the memory limit in the `phpunit.xml` file.

Comment: That example worked as explained. However, I coud not found any 'memory_limit' in the code. I will continue debugging. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that my code ofcourse could set the limit

Comment: That, right there, saved my day...
"So chances are your code is somewhere changing the memory limit back to 32M which is something phpunit can't "fix".

Answer (score 50):

For those who reach this thread and need to get the configuration for `phpunit.xml` configuration file:

```
<php>
  <ini name="memory_limit" value="512M" />
</php>
```

More on section "Setting PHP INI settings, Constants and Global Variables" at
https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Answer (score 14):

If you don't mind about the speed of the tests, found [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/laravel-5-phpunit-memory-allocation-exhausted) very useful as it's better handling of memory for your app.

Basically; In your `phpunit.xml`, under the  `<phpunit>` tag, set the `processIsolation` to `true` i.e

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit 
         ...
         processIsolation="true"
         ... >
```

Alternatively,

You can just disable memory limiting altogether under the  `<php>` tag, set the `memory_limit` to `-1` i.e

```
<php>
        ...
        <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
        ...
```